# In MySql, is it worthwhile creating more than one multi-column indexes on the same set of columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am new to SQL, and certainly to MySQL.
I have created a table from streaming market data named `trade` that looks like

```
 date     | time                  |instrument|price  |quantity
----------|-----------------------|----------|-------|--------
2017-09-08|2017-09-08 13:16:30.919|12899586  |54.15  |8000     
2017-09-08|2017-09-08 13:16:30.919|13793026  |1177.75|750      
2017-09-08|2017-09-08 13:16:30.919|1346049   |1690.8 |1         
2017-09-08|2017-09-08 13:16:30.919|261889    |110.85 |50
```

This table is huge (150 million rows per date). 
To retrieve data efficiently, I have created an index `date_time_inst (date,time,instrument)` because most of my queries will select a specific date
or date range and then a time range. 
But that does not help speed up a query like:

```
select * from trade where date="2017-09-08", instrument=261889
```

So, I am considering creating another index `date_inst_time (date, instrument, time)`. Will that help speed up queries where I wish to get the time-series of one or a few instruments out of the thousands? 
In additional database write-time due to index update, should I worry too much?

I get data every second, and take about 100 ms to process it and store in a database. As long as I continue to take less than 1 sec I am fine.

Comment: FYI, MySQL currently belongs to Oracle Corporation and has nothing to do with SQL Server, which belongs to Microsoft. I've removed such tag from your question.

Comment: Yes, additional Indexes woud help. I'd suggest to greate one index on all three fields starting with the most selective column, e.g. `(date,time,instrument)`. Then for other queries, where `date` or `time` is missing from the where clause, you'd have other indexes, but usually not on all three columns, as you create the indexes, because one of the columns is *not* relevant for those queries. E.g. `(time,instrument)`, `(date,instrument)`, `(instrument)`. But yes, insert time will increase; I don't know by how much.

Comment: Why do you have date and time separated by the way? You'd usually only do this when one of the two can be null (e.g. to express a daily reoccuring time or a whole-day event). Is this the case in your scenario?

Comment: No. The only reason to retain date separately is because I foresaw the need of a partition. Usually in kdb, a columnar database that I am used to, we partition by date (which essentially makes folders for each date on disk) and splay the columns (which essentially stores each column for a date in a separate file). Not sure, the equivalent best practices in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

To get the most efficient query you need to query on a clustered index. According the [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) this is automatically set on the primary key and can not be set on any other columns.

I would suggest ditching the `date` column and creating a composite primary key on `time` and `instrument`

Comment: Thanks. I had a primary key (date,time,instrument) when I created the table. But unfortunately, I didn't realize datetime type needs to be explicitly told to store millisecond precision by saying datetime(3). It defaulted to seconds' precision, thereby creating non-unique key values. I later fixed the error, but my initial 2-3 days of data has made the choice for a primary key difficult. (i.e. when a price changes more than once in a second).

Comment: Hmmm that does sound like a bit of a difficult situation. Can you "fix" the timestamps - assuming that they were entered in time order?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of recommendations:

- There is no need to store date and time separately if time corresponds to time of the same `date`. You can instead have one `datetime` column and store timestamps in it
- You can then have one index on `datetime` and `instrument` columns, that will make the queries run faster
- With so many inserts and fixed format of `SELECT` query (i.e. always by `date` first, followed by `instrument`), I would suggest looking into other columnar databases (like Cassandra). You will get faster writes and reads for such structure

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I can drop the date easily, the only reason for creating a separate column was for creating a partition later. Guess that can be done by datetime range too. Let me evaluate Cassandra too.

Answer (score 0):

First, your use case sounds like two indexes would be useful `(date, instrument)` and `(date, time)`.

Given your volume of data, you may want to consider partitioning the data.  This involves storing different "shards" of data in different files.  One place to start is with the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html).

From your description, you would want to partition by `date`, although `instrument` is another candidate.

Another approach would be a clustered index with `date` as the first column in the index.  This assumes that the data is inserted "in order", to reduce movement of the data on inserts.

You are dealing with a large quantity of data.  MySQL should be able to handle the volume.  But, you may need to dive into more advanced functionality, such as partitioning and clustered indexes to get the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Typo?**

I assume you meant

```
select * from trade where date="2017-09-08" AND instrument=261889
                                            ^^^
```

**Optimal index** for such is

```
INDEX(instrument, date)
```

And, contrary to other Comments/Answers, it is better to have the `date` *last*, especially if you want more than one day.

**Splitting date and time**

It is usually a bad idea to split date and time.  It is also usually a bad idea to have redundant data; in this case, the *date* is repeated.  Instead, use

```
WHERE `time` >= "2017-09-08"
  AND `time`  < "2017-09-08" + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

and get rid of the `date` column.  Note:  This pattern works for `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DATETIME(3)`, etc, without messing up with the midnight at the end of the range.

**Data volume?**

150M rows?  10 new rows per second?  That means you have about 5 years' data?  A steady 10/sec insertion rate is rarely a problem.

Need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If there are a lot of indexes, then there could be a problem.  Need to see the datatypes to look for shrinking the size.

Will you be purging 'old' data?  If so, we need to talk about partitioning for that specific purpose.

How many "instruments"?  How much RAM?  Need to discuss the ramifications of an index *starting* with `instrument`.

**The query**

Is that the main `SELECT` you use?  Is it always 1 day?  One instrument?  How many rows are typically returned.

Depending on the `PRIMARY KEY` and whatever index is used, fetching 100 rows could take anywhere from 10ms to 1000ms.  Is this issue important?

**Millisecond resolution**

It is usually folly to think that *any* time resolution is not going to have duplicates.

Is there an `AUTO_INCREMENT` already?

Answer (score 0):

SPACE IS CHEAP. Indexes take time creating/inserting (once), but shave time retrieving (Many many times)

My experience is to create as many indexes with all the *relevant* fields in all orders. This way, Mysql can choose the best index for your query.

So if you have 3 relevant fields

```
INDEX 1 (field1,field2,field3)
INDEX 2 (field1,field3)
INDEX 3 (field2,field3)
INDEX 4 (field3)
```

The first index will be used when all fields are present. The others are for shorter WHERE conditions.

Unless you know that some combinations will never be used, this will give MySQL the best chance to optimize your query. I'm also assuming that `field1` is the biggest driver of the data.